# OpenGL ES shader to convert color image to black-and-white infrared?

Tags: image-processing, opengl-es, shader

I was able to create a fragment shader to convert a color image to greyscale, by:

```
 float luminance = pixelColor.r * 0.299 + pixelColor.g * 0.587 + pixelColor.b * 0.114;
 gl_FragColor = vec4(luminance, luminance, luminance, 1.0);
```

Now I'd like to mimic a Photoshop channel mixer effect:

[image: Black & White Infrared]

How can I translate the `%` percentage values (-70%, +200%, -30%) into `r g b` floating point numbers (e.g. 0.299, 0.587, 0.114)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should know from school that 10% of a value means multiplying that value by 0.1, so just use `(-0.7, 2.0, -0.3)`.

Comment: I don't think it's the same Range, the photoshop's one go to -200% to 200% while Float Color go from 0 to 1, so I guess it's not the same calculation

Comment: No thats wrong, if you add together all values you get a total of 1.0 (100%) -> -0.7 + 2.0 - 0.3 = 1.0. One problem might be the negative values. If you get problems with that just add 1 to every value and divide that by 4. -> ((-0.7 + 1) + (2.0 + 1) +(-0.3 + 1)) / 4 = 1